# ImageView setClickable(true) ... setPressed(true) not staying pressed

Tags: android

I've got an `ImageView` which I'm setting to `setImageResource(R.drawable.someStateListDrawable)`. Everything works fine, when it's clicked, it shows the pressed state. However, I've made it so that it `onClick`, the `ImageView` is set to "`setPressed(true)`" so that it will remain in the pressed state. But for some reason, its not... Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had this same problem with a Button. When `onClick` I set it to the pressed state ( `btn.setPressed(true)` ) but after that the button wasn't pressed.

In case this helps somebody, I finally worked with the selected state. My drawable xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

and at `onClick` I now use `btn.setSelected( true )`.

I don't know what was the problem with `setPressed`, but this worked for me.

Comment: Yeah I've since discovered this too. Thanks!

Comment: I've been struggling with this for hours! It seems Android is changing the "pressed" state both before and after onClick... Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860085/force-a-listview-item-to-stay-pressed-after-being-clicked) question? He basically says use a selector, and in the xml do something like this:

> ```
> <item android:state_pressed="true"   
>     android:drawable="@color/gray" />
> ```

Of course you would need to modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Of course, I already defined a pressed state in my Selector. That's why it switches to the pressed state when clicked. I'd just like it to say pressed.